# Unable to use npm in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, progressive-web-apps

I have followed available tutorials and searched around for answers but cannot find them. I have just added the npm package via the extensions tab and restarted the computer. I cannot get npm to be recognized in the terminal:

```
PS E:\Web Apps> npm
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized...
```

Does this have to do with the directory? If so, not sure where to change the directory to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use npm on the terminal, you need to install nodejs. See [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-node-js-npm-on-windows) for window instruction.

Answer (score 1):

You must install NodeJS in your system to access npm.
You can install it from https://nodejs.org/en/download/